# Object.prototype are not enumerable?

Tags: prototype, enumerable

This is probably stupid but could you Please explain me this quote, because I think I don’t understand this the way I should.
“Properties inherited from Object.prototype are not enumerable, so the for/in loop does not show them”
So why the for in loop below show me print function and author property ?

```
function PrintStuff (myDocuments) {
this.documents = myDocuments;
}
PrintStuff.prototype.print = function () {
console.log(this.documents);
}
PrintStuff.prototype.author = “Stephen King”;
var newObj = new PrintStuff();
for (x in newObj) {
console.log(x);
}  
//documents, print, author.
```

Comment: _for in loop below show me print function and author property_ because it not in `Object.prototype` but in `PrintStuff.prototype`. But you not see properties from `Object.prototype` like _toString()_.